# div false not working with input submit cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, form-helpers

I am using Form Helper to create an input `submit` button but I am confused as to why `'div'=>false` is not working for me.

Here is my php code:

```
echo $this->Form->input('Save', 
            array('type'=>"submit",
                  'class'=>'btn btn-primary',
                  'div'=>false, 
                  'label'=>false));
```

Which gives me output:

```
<div class="submit"><!--unwanted div-->
  <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Save">
</div>
```

But when I tried with input `'type'=>'button'` it works like:

```
echo $this->Form->input('Save', 
            array('type'=>"button",
                  'class'=>'btn btn-primary',
                  'div'=>false, 
                  'label'=>false));
```

And gives me perfect output:

```
<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Save">
```

But I don't want this extra div with type `submit`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
echo $this->Form->submit('Save',
                   array('div'=>false,
                   "class"=>"btn btn-primary"
                   ));
```

Answer (score 1):

In cakePHP 3 you should use:

```
echo $this->Form->input(__('Save'), [
'type'=>'submit',
'label'=>false,
'templates' => ['submitContainer' => '{{content}}']  //important part
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
    echo $this->Form->submit('Add person',
    array('div'=>false,
          'class' =>'btn btn-primary',
          'label'=>false));
```

If you try this one then its hide one div (`<div class="input submit">`).

```
echo $this->Form->input('Save', 
        array('type'=>"submit",
              'class'=>'btn btn-primary',
              'div'=>false, 
              'label'=>false));
```